# Why do I get duplicate network interfaces?

Tags: windows-10, networking, powershell, dhcp

While troubleshooting connectivity issues on my PC, I noticed that I have duplicate of every network interface when issuing `Get-NetIPInterface` command on PowerShell.

Notice how each interface has a duplicate. Even the `ifIndex`'s are the same.

But I can conclude that these are not just "shadows" of the same interface, because one of `vEthernet (Ethernet 2)` has DHCP **Enabled** and the other one **Disabled**.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetIPInterface

ifIndex InterfaceAlias                  AddressFamily NlMtu(Bytes) InterfaceMetric Dhcp     ConnectionState PolicyStore
------- --------------                  ------------- ------------ --------------- ----     --------------- -----------
37      vEthernet (WSL)                 IPv6                  1500            5000 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
21      Ethernet 2                      IPv6                  1500               6 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
31      vEthernet (Ethernet 2)          IPv6                  1500              15 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv6            4294967295              75 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
37      vEthernet (WSL)                 IPv4                  1500            5000 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
21      Ethernet 2                      IPv4                  1500               6 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
31      vEthernet (Ethernet 2)          IPv4                  1500              15 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv4            4294967295              75 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
```

Network connections (`ncpa.cpl`) window doesn't show the duplicates.

[image: Network connections]

Why do I get these duplicate network interfaces, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not the list of link-layer interfaces (that's `Get-NetAdapter`), it's a list of *IP interfaces* or network stacks. As can be seen from the 3rd column ("AddressFamily"), one entry represents the **IPv4** configuration of that interface and the other represents **IPv6** configuration. (The two protocols are basically independent network stacks that only share the same link layer – but each has its own addresses, routes, gateways, static/DHCP settings, etc.)

Comment: Now that makes sense! :) Thanks. But still I wonder why they have the same `ifIndex`...

Comment: Because ifIndex is always assigned to "physical" / link-layer interfaces (not just on Windows but other systems as well), i.e. it's not the index of the Get-NetIPInterface output but a property of the whole "Ethernet" interface from Get-NetAdapter.

Comment: (The name `ifIndex` comes from SNMP, specifically from [IF-MIB](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/IF-MIB.txt) schema.)